# What am I missing? Basic Set-Cartesian Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ have $3$, $4$ and $5$ elements respectively then how many elements $A\times B\times C$ has?
There is no further information about the sets.
This was a multiple choice exam and answer were like this

A-)60
B-)12
C-)30
D-)20

I thought we should just multiply the numbers and get $3\cdot4\cdot5=60$

What am I missing? This answer looks wrong according to my exam analysis.

Comment: See [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cardinality): it must be 60.

Comment: This is the third question where the "correct" answer according to the text is wrong; it seems to me that there is something definitely wrong in the papers you are using...

Comment: That is probably what I am going to say if the instructor gives me an answer. I guess not all the answers in the answer key is wrong but they have variety of questions with little differences and they mixed up. There were 20 questions and in first 14 questions it looks I have 2 mistakes but 5 of last 6 looks completely wrong. I will also ask the questions that I really did not get.